# How to get progress back in activity class android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing android FTP Client. I am using async task for each network function. In my design I am using a controller for calling networking task. Actually I have three class 1st is activity from where user selects any function, according to selected function i call controller method, controller method calls network class async task. All functions are doing function. 
Now my current problem is to display a progress bar while file downloading/uploading. Progress bar will display on activity class but my progress is in network class. I am stuck here, how to get back progress in controller and then in activity where progress bar will be updated.

So can anyone guide me how to get result back from network class onProgressUpdate() method to controller class and from controller to my activity class. I have calculated progress in onProgressUpdate() correctly, only problem is to get back the this progress in activity class.

Comment: Check out this sample project: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/worker-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Some of async tasc methods can edit UI Thread:

`onPreExecute()` - Called before starting AsyncTasc - used to start progressbar
`onProgressUpdate()` - Called from doInBackground - used to set progressbar progress
`onPostExecute()` - Called after finish AsyncTasc - used to clear progressbar

`doInBackground()` - Used for asynctasc, method `publishProgress()` calls `onProgressUpdate()`

Comment: I know how to use the async task method. I have calculated the progress in onProgressUpdate() my question is how I can get the result in controller and then activity.

Comment: Please guide me how to use observer or other other pattern in this problem to get the solution

Comment: Have you AsyncTasc class in file with Activity class?

Comment: yes I have async task class, a controller class and activity class. activity calls controller class method, controller calls async class that starts now task

Comment: Code is like this, only example code activity class---method show dialog --- this method calls controller method ---int getProgress() --this method creates a anync task that returns result onProgressUpdate(). so my problem is to get progress result in controller class and then in activity class